# write out formula with paste

Tags: r, formula, paste

there is a vector (called f)

```
f
3 4 8
```

it indicates which columns from a dataframe (y) should be included in a model. The column names of these columns are FER7, TOJ9, GHY11. Can somebody tell me how I could achieve that

```
response~factor(FER7)+factor(TOJ9)+factor(GHY111)
```

with paste or something similar. I will then only need to make it as.formula and feed it the function. There is a way but I just dont see it in th moment

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
 as.formula(paste0('response~', paste('factor',
              '(', names(y)[f],')', sep="",collapse="+")))
 #response ~ factor(FER7) + factor(TOJ9) + factor(GHY111)
```

#### data

```
f <- c(3,4,8)
set.seed(24)
y <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:100, 9*10, replace=TRUE), ncol=9) )
colnames(y) <- c('response', 'T1', 'FER7', 'TOJ9', 'TOJ10',
                  'TOJ11', 'TOJ12', 'GHY111', 'GHY12')
```